# C++ const : how come the compiler doesn't give a warning/error

Tags: c++, constants

Really simple question about C++ constness.

So I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const), then I tried out this code:

```
int some_num = 5;
const int* some_num_ptr = &some_num;
```

How come the compiler doesn't give an error or at least a warning?

The way I read the statement above, it says:

```
Create a pointer that points to a constant integer
```

But some_num is not a constant integer--it's just an int.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is in how you're reading the code.  It should actually read

> Create a pointer to an integer where the value cannot be modified via the pointer

A `const int*` in C++ makes no guarantees that the `int` is constant.  It is simply a tool to make it harder to modify the original value via the pointer

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Jared Par's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246996/c-const-how-come-the-compiler-doesnt/2247016#2247016).  Also, check out the [C++ FAQ on const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.5 -> Helped me understand in a jiffy :)

Answer (score 2):

The const keyword just tells the compiler that you want some stricter checking on your variable.
Castring a non const integer to a const integer pointer is valid, and just tells the compiler that it should give an error if you try to change the value of the contents of the const-pointer.

In other words, writing

```
*some_num_ptr = 6;
```

should give an error since the pointer points to a const int.

Writing

```
some_num = 7;
```

remains valid of course.

Answer (score 0):

`int* ptr;` just says you can't change the valued pointed to by `ptr` through `ptr`. The actual value might still be changed by other means.

(the actual reason the compiler doesn't warn is that casts from T* to const T* are implicit)